# react native connect to classic bluetooth device on ios

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, bluetooth, core-bluetooth

I’m trying to connect my application to a Bluetooth device (classic Bluetooth device) ON
And I’ve installed the library ‘react-native-bluetooth-serial’
and it's working on android, but not on IOS
Now when I’m running the application I get these messages in the Xcode console:

```
[CoreBluetooth] XPC connection invalid
 Known peripherals : 0
 List of currently known peripherals :
```

How should I connect the Bluetooth device in react native?

Comment: iOS apps cannot connect to classic Bluetooth devices. You can only use Bluetooth Low Energy GATT devices with iOS apps (unless the hardware is mfi certified which I assume yours isn't).

Comment: and if I get this certification? will I be able to search for a classic bluetooth device nearby and connect? 
for now, I'm only talking about the development, not publish it to the store

Comment: in the 'react-native-bluetooth-classic' library I can connect to paired devices in IOS, but - I can't get a list of unpaired devices and chose the device from the unpaired list

Comment: The Bluetooth device needs to be an mfi device and include an mfi chip from Apple. Unless you are the device manufacturer there is nothing you can do.